# How to configure ROUGE properties file for ROUGE-SU4

Tags: nlp, rouge

I am using ROUGE for evaluating summary.I follow all the steps given in http://kavita-ganesan.com/content/rouge-2.0-documentation . I get results upto ROUGE 3 but I am facing problem for ROUGE-L and ROUGE-SU-4.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same question as well. I have checked on the website: http://www.rxnlp.com/rouge-2-0/
It seems to be the version 2.0 only supports the following features:

Features
ROUGE 2.0 currently supports the following:

```
- Evaluation of ROUGE-N (unigram, bigrams, trigrams, etc)
- Stemming for different languages
- Stopword removal with customizable stop words
- Evalutation of unicode texts (e.g. Persian)
- Synonyms capture for better agreement between system and reference summaries [English only and requires WordNet installation]
- Evaluation of specific parts of speech (e.g. NN) [Uses Stanford POS Tagger]
```

Answer (score 1):

ROUGE S, L, SU are now supported. Latest documentation can be found in the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/RxNLP/ROUGE-2.0).